# Consulta multiple de mysql utilizando handlebars

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, handlebars.js

Estoy realizando una página web que me muestre los productos de un local, el problema es el siguiente, el cliente accederá a una determinada ruta y se realizarán 2 consultas, la primera es para mostrar la información de las categorías existentes de productos y la segunda me traerá la información de los productos, todo va bien hasta que necesito realizar la consulta de los productos ya que quiero mostrar la foto de ellos mediante el id de la categoría, no sé si me explico lo suficiente pero creo que adjuntando el código tendrán una idea.

Adjunto el script:

```
router.get('/productos', async (req, res) =>{
    const obj = {};
    const categorias = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM categoria_producto');
    for(let i = 0; i < categorias.length; i++){
        obj[i] = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM productost WHERE id_cp2 = ?', categorias[i].id_cp);
    }
    console.log(obj);
    res.render('productos/productos', {categorias, obj});
});
```

Como ven he intentado guardar la consulta en un objeto y enviarlo pero no da con el problema.

Adjunto código html:

```html
{{#each categorias}}
<h3 style="margin-left: 3%;">Productos de {{nombre_cp}} que te pueden interesar</h3>

<p>{{id_cp}}</p>
<div id="categorias_productos">
    {{#each ../obj}}
    <div id="imagen_producto">
        <p>{{nombre_p}}</p>
        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/{{foto_p}}" alt="logo" width="300" height="400"></a>
    </div>
    {{/each}}

</div>

{{/each}}
```

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Cual es el problema?

Comment: no puedo desplegar la información del producto según su categoria